Upload file to Google Drive API using Multipart body
I am trying to upload a file to a Google Drive API directly without using Google Drive Nuget.
I tried using different approaches with MultipartFormDataContent and still I was not able to uploaded. The server always responds with 400 - Parse Error or 400 - Unable to parse number.
string _fileUploadMultipartUrl = "files?uploadType=multipart";
var fileMetadata = new GoogleFileCreateModel(fileName, _mimeTypeFile, parentId is not null ? new[] { parentId } : null);
var metadataJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(fileMetadata);
var mediaJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize("{}");

// Define a unique boundary string
string boundary = "foo_bar_baz";

// Construct the request body
StringBuilder requestBody = new StringBuilder();

// Part 1: Metadata
requestBody.AppendLine($"--{boundary}");
requestBody.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
requestBody.AppendLine();
requestBody.AppendLine(metadataJson);
requestBody.AppendLine($"--{boundary}");

// Part 2: Media
requestBody.AppendLine($"Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
requestBody.AppendLine();
requestBody.AppendLine(mediaJson);
requestBody.AppendLine($"--{boundary}--"); // Double hyphen at the end

var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody.ToString());
ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=" + boundary);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _fileUploadMultipartUrl)
{
    Content = content,
};

_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "my-token");
var result = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

I also tried:
var fileMetadata = new GoogleFileCreateModel(fileName, _mimeTypeFile, parentId is not null ? new[] { parentId } : null);

var metadataContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(fileMetadata));
metadataContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json", "charset=utf-8");

var mediaJson= "{\"Data\":\"AAA\"}";
var mediaContent = new StringContent(mediaJson);
mediaContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json", "charset=utf-8");

using MultipartFormDataContent form = new ()
{
    { metadataContent, "metadata" },
    { mediaContent, "media" }
};

var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _fileUploadMultipartUrl)
{
    Content = form,
};

// Send it

Both with no success. Could you please help me with uploading a file to a Google Drive Api v3 without using Drive Nuget?
I was able to successfully upload it using Postman.

what line is throwing the error

It is not throwing an error. _httpClient.SendAsync returns 400 - Bad Request
